# an api for adding label to device

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add gmail feature of moving the mail to custom created label or already made label. It is a move to label feature. When you select the mail and then click on move to label actions, you will see lots of pre-defined label name such as important, sms, personal, work etc and also a create a new label in the dropdown. I want to have get, post and delete. Am i on the right track?

**Here is my model**

```
class Device(BaseDevice):
"""
This stores Device
"""
# Description is optional (can be blank, can be null)
description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_on= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Label(models.Model):
    """
    This creates a label
    """
    # Name is required
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name='label')
```

**Serializers**

```
class IOSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex')
    class Meta:
        model = IO
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'type')

class LabelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex')
    class Meta:
      model = Label 
      fields = ('id', 'name')

class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex', read_only=True)
    label = LabelSerializer(read_only=False, many=True, required=False)
    io = IOSerializer(read_only=False, many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'io', 'label')

    def save_io(self, device, io):
        for io in io:
            token = io.pop('token', None)
            if token is None:
                IO.objects.create(device=device, **io)
            else:
                IO.objects.filter(token=token, device=device).update(**io)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        io = validated_data.pop('io',[])
        instance = super(DeviceSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

        if len(io):
            self.save_io(instance, io)

        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        io = validated_data.pop('io',[])
        instance = super(DeviceSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        if len(io):
            self.save_io(instance, io)

        return instance
```